# How can I use 2 different SSL certificates for 2 different service provider?

Tags: java

In my project I have 2 service providers. For the first one we have SSL certificate installed on server truststore. Recently we implemented the code for the other one for which we kept keystore in server's /security folder.
To invoke the second service we use keystore using

`System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",keystore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",keystorePassword);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType","PKCS12");`

For laodbalancing we have 2 jetty servers where application is deployed.
Now when we trigger the second service, sometimes it runs successfully from either of servers and sometime fails. We checked with the service provider for the failure. As per the second service provider, the request is picking up certificate for the first service provider and hence failing at second service provider with error code 403. Providing the exception stacktrace as below,

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response: (403null
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:148)
at com.toyota.tme.coc.ereg.client.UtacSoapClient.callTheWebServiceFromFile(UtacSoapClient.java:269)
at com.toyota.tme.coc.ereg.client.UtacSoapClient.sendEreg(UtacSoapClient.java:98)
at com.toyota.tme.coc.ereg.client.EregInvocationClientImpl.sendEregToFrance(EregInvocationClientImpl.java:714)
at com.toyota.tme.coc.ereg.client.EregInvocationClientImpl.invokeIviService(EregInvocationClientImpl.java:292)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.invokeIviService(Unknown Source)
at com.toyota.tme.coc.backend.mdp.SendEregMainframeListener.triggerProcess(SendEregMainframeListener.java:70)
at com.toyota.tme.coc.backend.mdp.MainframeListener.onMessage(MainframeListener.java:64)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:562)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:500)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:326)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:264)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1071)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1063)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:960)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response: (403null
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:257)
    at `enter code here`com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
    ... 22 more

Can someone help with this problem with any clue?
Thanks in advance!